# Heroku rails - ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token: name

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run my project locally, everything works fine; however, when I deploy to the Heroku environment with the same ruby and rails version, I get an error when trying to create `new text_message`.

This is the error in the logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token: name (tags) (line: 23, col: 8, pos: 352)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.188865+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text_messages/new.html.erb within layouts/application (335.6ms)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.189147+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 344ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191422+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191423+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:11936)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191419+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191422+00:00 app[web.1]: Error
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191425+00:00 app[web.1]:     at token_error (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:20759)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191424+00:00 app[web.1]:     at js_error (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:12155)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:22152
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191425+00:00 app[web.1]:     at croak (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:20622)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at semicolon (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:21320)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:21493
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at block_ (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:26198)):
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:20847)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191430+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191427+00:00 app[web.1]:     at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20170713-4-hxjahdjs:2659:24179)
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191432+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= javascript_include_tag "text_messages"%>
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191430+00:00 app[web.1]:      9: <%= javascript_include_tag "forms"%>
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191434+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/text_messages/new.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_text_messages_new_html_erb___3722409297874948535_69990020802000'
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191431+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191435+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191432+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191433+00:00 app[web.1]:     13: <%= form_for @text_message, url: text_messages_path do |f| %>
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191435+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-13T16:44:31.191433+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:
```

I've been debugging the issue for some time now and I've been able to pin the error to this line in my `new.html.erb` file:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "text_messages"%>`

I have all of my javascript in a file called `text_messages.js` and when I include it with that line, the page doesn't work.

I first checked the contents of the `js` file to see if there was anything with `tags` that might have caused the issue but there is nothing at all.

Then, I deleted the contents of my `text_messages.js` file... and the error persisted. Even after clearing the cache. Then, I put the javascript from `text_messages.js` in the `new.html.erb` file and there was no error.

So, the result is that the error is in including the file and not the actual file or contents of it...

Not sure what to do but I've been able to narrow the error to the aforementioned... any ideas?

Comment: Hey @Walker, do you also have a `text_messages.coffee` file in your `app/assets/javascripts`?

Comment: @kparekh01 No i don't. I only have `text_message.js` ... should I have a `.coffee`? and what should go in there? Thanks

Comment: No @Walker a .coffee file with the same name was a culprit in a similar problem I had with deployment to Heroku.  One more question, does your github repo have a .coffee file with the same name in `app/assets/javascripts/?`

Comment: @kparekh01 nope not a single one.

Comment: One other thing could be that in your `views\layouts\application.html.erb` there is already an include tag there that is requiring the `application.js` file.  I copied this from my `views\layouts\application.html.erb` : `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>`.  Have you tried to remove your include tag in new.html.erb for both  text_messages and form, push up to github and heroku and try running the app again?

Comment: it could be requiring it twice that could be causing an issue.

Comment: @kparekh01 I'm doing `//= stub 'text_messages'` in my `application.js` file because I don't want that `js` loaded with every file. Thanks a lot for your help man I appreciate you taking the time.